# Convert android vector drawable to SVG

Tags: xml, android-studio, svg

How to convert this file to SVG?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:height="dimension(28161)"
android:width="dimension(28161)"
android:viewportWidth="1121714176.000000"
android:viewportHeight="1121714176.000000">

<group
    android:translateX="1101529088.000000"
    android:translateY="1090519040.000000">

    <path
        android:name="hair1"
        android:fillColor="rgb8(0xff0572cc)"
        android:pathData="M13.6680389 87.8907808C13.6680389 87.8907808 15.555746 93.5954113 17.6983406 93.7540446C19.8409352 93.9126779 21.0469466 91.9482686 21.0469466 91.9482686C21.0469466 91.9482686 23.4880504 94.1488653 25.7751953 93.9919946C28.0640509 93.8342426 28.8073302 90.4068815 28.8073302 90.4068815C28.8073302 90.4068815 29.1896615 91.8416318 31.0277596 91.7323511C32.8658578 91.6230703 33.4945233 89.4118981 33.4945233 89.4118981C33.4945233 89.4118981 33.2011461 87.8907808 36.7362134 87.8907808C40.2712807 87.8907808 38.842492 70.768022 39.5040522 70.3760024C40.8990908 69.5502278 38.8873613 67.9154344 38.2407339 66.6796779C37.5941065 65.4439213 36.364146 65.8530872 37.7933978 64.6968266C39.2226495 63.5405659 38.2407339 60.9275226 38.2407339 60.9275226C38.2407339 60.9275226 38.5614816 59.0935451 37.7839892 57.4472838C37.0064968 55.8010224 34.0812777 53.6374402 34.0812777 53.6374402C34.0812777 53.6374402 36.0605049 50.1140178 36.4505341 46.8223764C36.8414186 43.530735 38.408378 38.5205659 36.2846006 37.2938016C34.1608232 36.0670372 32.6451834 34.7838699 33.6561801 33.2865476C34.6680322 31.788344 35.5926409 29.6476755 35.1855052 28.8879981C34.7783694 28.1274395 36.4761939 24.939791 35.7406125 24.2091964C35.0058864 23.4794832 33.3901734 21.613779 34.2985309 20.3323743C35.2068883 19.0500883 38.6863594 18.2639721 39.5040522 17.142082C40.321745 16.0201919 40.7955962 14.7617008 40.7955962 14.7617008C40.7955962 14.7617008 42.8321303 15.8148498 44.2023645 15.1908921C45.573454 14.5660531 47.1489667 11.3123074 47.1489667 11.3123074C47.1489667 11.3123074 48.3370161 13.1330654 50.9705686 12.7964102C53.6049763 12.4597551 53.7734758 11.0338178 53.7734758 11.0338178C53.7734758 11.0338178 56.7902148 12.6386582 59.4143587 12.0781538C62.0376472 11.5176494 62.625257 9.24126125 62.625257 9.24126125C62.625257 9.24126125 65.3417762 11.1378107 67.2063894 8.78122462C69.0710027 6.42463849 69.780069 3.40355502 67.8726893 3.16384244L65.9653097 2.92412987L66.0730809 4.83742398C66.0730809 4.83742398 65.2331496 0.75790373 63.6148705 0.899792423C61.9965915 1.04168112 61.6903843 2.03930845 61.6903843 2.03930845L62.4516256 3.15855466C62.4516256 3.15855466 61.9102034 1.48585442 59.561475 1.59160996C57.2136018 1.69648422 57.3136751 3.01314078 57.3136751 3.01314078C57.3136751 3.01314078 56.9664122 0.522597636 53.7195902 0.559612078C50.4736235 0.595745224 50.1109647 3.65208055 50.1109647 3.65208055C50.1109647 3.65208055 50.3094007 -0.0925471327 46.6383363 0.00175156402C42.967272 0.0960502607 43.5771203 4.06981497 43.5771203 4.06981497C43.5771203 4.06981497 41.3729421 0.78610521 36.7362134 3.4308752C32.0994846 6.07652648 34.7056666 10.5244286 34.7056666 10.5244286C34.7056666 10.5244286 32.092642 8.86759165 29.7832586 11.0223609C27.4747305 13.1771302 27.1642467 16.7014338 27.1642467 16.7014338C27.1642467 16.7014338 25.8453322 15.9787709 24.1073073 17.8744391C22.3692824 19.7718699 23.5376594 22.6722158 23.5376594 22.6722158C23.5376594 22.6722158 21.4874401 23.5579185 21.2659103 25.4227413C21.0452359 27.2884455 21.3428898 28.4226737 21.3428898 28.4226737C21.3428898 28.4226737 18.2962143 29.5031429 17.8257844 32.5612408C17.3544991 35.62022 18.1183063 36.4706709 18.1183063 36.4706709C18.1183063 36.4706709 15.9902522 38.0094141 15.0493923 39.5613768C14.1093877 41.1133394 14.6337033 43.0671732 14.6337033 43.0671732C14.6337033 43.0671732 12.6484888 43.4082348 11.1183085 45.3726441C9.58812812 47.3361721 10.5537925 50.1298812 10.5537925 50.1298812C10.5537925 50.1298812 8.9175516 50.2585504 7.84668195 52.9068456C6.7758123 55.5560221 7.35657946 57.037481 7.35657946 57.037481C7.35657946 57.037481 5.74172172 56.0724617 4.26115034 57.6226617C2.78057896 59.1728618 4.49636532 63.7256381 4.49636532 63.7256381C4.49636532 63.7256381 2.40680097 63.1281193 1.26836047 65.4344715C0.129919975 67.7408238 1.6087807 68.9385053 1.6087807 68.9385053C1.6087807 68.9385053 -0.334522693 71.0227709 0.0939962327 73.1925222L0.909978379 75.0309062C0.909978379 75.0309062 -1.31130635 79.8348519 1.18710439 82.0759883C3.68637046 84.3171246 5.49111085 83.0295508 5.49111085 83.0295508C5.49111085 83.0295508 3.1090246 85.4152197 4.91376499 87.4175247C6.71850538 89.420711 8.08446291 88.2529935 8.08446291 88.2529935C8.08446291 88.2529935 7.9835343 90.1292732 11.2491735 91.7543835C13.7775207 93.0128745 13.6680389 87.8907808 13.6680389 87.8907808Z"
        android:fillType="1" />

    <path
        android:pathData="M11.2491735 91.7543835C13.7775207 93.0128745 13.6680389 87.8907808 13.6680389 87.8907808C13.6680389 87.8907808 15.555746 93.5954113 17.6983406 93.7540446C19.8409352 93.9126779 21.0469466 91.9482686 21.0469466 91.9482686C21.0469466 91.9482686 23.4880504 94.1488653 25.7751953 93.9919946C28.0640509 93.8342426 28.8073302 90.4068815 28.8073302 90.4068815C28.8073302 90.4068815 29.1896615 91.8416318 31.0277596 91.7323511C32.8658578 91.6230703 33.2772702 89.8851542 34.0812777 87.8907808C34.3521489 87.2188739 37.7731929 88.6849417 38.2407339 86.236289C38.6264912 84.2159624 39.682448 81.9103573 39.5040522 79.1689654C39.256883 75.3707399 38.4604451 71.3828691 38.9977154 71.0644997C40.3927541 70.2387251 40.1506795 68.4816333 39.5040522 67.6482127C38.8574248 66.814792 36.364146 65.8530872 37.7933978 64.6968266C39.2226495 63.5405659 38.2407339 60.9275226 38.2407339 60.9275226C38.2407339 60.9275226 38.5614816 59.0935451 37.7839892 57.4472838C37.0064968 55.8010224 34.0812777 53.6374402 34.0812777 53.6374402C34.0812777 53.6374402 36.0605049 50.1140178 36.4505341 46.8223764C36.8414186 43.530735 38.408378 38.5205659 36.2846006 37.2938016C34.1608232 36.0670372 32.6451834 34.7838699 33.6561801 33.2865476C34.6680322 31.788344 35.5926409 29.6476755 35.1855052 28.8879981C34.7783694 28.1274395 36.4761939 24.939791 35.7406125 24.2091964C35.0058864 23.4794832 33.3901734 21.613779 34.2985309 20.3323743C35.2068883 19.0500883 38.6863594 18.2639721 39.5040522 17.142082C40.321745 16.0201919 40.7955962 14.7617008 40.7955962 14.7617008C40.7955962 14.7617008 42.8321303 15.8148498 44.2023645 15.1908921C45.573454 14.5660531 47.1489667 11.3123074 47.1489667 11.3123074C47.1489667 11.3123074 48.3370161 13.1330654 50.9705686 12.7964102C53.6049763 12.4597551 53.7734758 11.0338178 53.7734758 11.0338178C53.7734758 11.0338178 56.7902148 12.6386582 59.4143587 12.0781538C62.0376472 11.5176494 62.625257 9.24126125 62.625257 9.24126125C62.625257 9.24126125 65.3417762 11.1378107 67.2063894 8.78122462C69.0710027 6.42463849 69.780069 3.40355502 67.8726893 3.16384244L65.9653097 2.92412987L66.0730809 4.83742398C66.0730809 4.83742398 65.2331496 0.75790373 63.6148705 0.899792423C61.9965915 1.04168112 61.6903843 2.03930845 61.6903843 2.03930845L62.4516256 3.15855466C62.4516256 3.15855466 61.9102034 1.48585442 59.561475 1.59160996C57.2136018 1.69648422 57.3136751 3.01314078 57.3136751 3.01314078C57.3136751 3.01314078 56.9664122 0.522597636 53.7195902 0.559612078C50.4736235 0.595745224 50.1109647 3.65208055 50.1109647 3.65208055C50.1109647 3.65208055 50.3094007 -0.0925471327 46.6383363 0.00175156402C42.967272 0.0960502607 43.5771203 4.06981497 43.5771203 4.06981497C43.5771203 4.06981497 41.3729421 0.78610521 36.7362134 3.4308752C32.0994846 6.07652648 34.7056666 10.5244286 34.7056666 10.5244286C34.7056666 10.5244286 32.092642 8.86759165 29.7832586 11.0223609C27.4747305 13.1771302 27.1642467 16.7014338 27.1642467 16.7014338C27.1642467 16.7014338 25.8453322 15.9787709 24.1073073 17.8744391C22.3692824 19.7718699 23.5376594 22.6722158 23.5376594 22.6722158C23.5376594 22.6722158 21.4874401 23.5579185 21.2659103 25.4227413C21.0452359 27.2884455 21.3428898 28.4226737 21.3428898 28.4226737C21.3428898 28.4226737 18.2962143 29.5031429 17.8257844 32.5612408C17.3544991 35.62022 18.1183063 36.4706709 18.1183063 36.4706709C18.1183063 36.4706709 15.9902522 38.0094141 15.0493923 39.5613768C14.1093877 41.1133394 14.6337033 43.0671732 14.6337033 43.0671732C14.6337033 43.0671732 12.6484888 43.4082348 11.1183085 45.3726441C9.58812812 47.3361721 10.5537925 50.1298812 10.5537925 50.1298812C10.5537925 50.1298812 8.9175516 50.2585504 7.84668195 52.9068456C6.7758123 55.5560221 7.35657946 57.037481 7.35657946 57.037481C7.35657946 57.037481 5.74172172 56.0724617 4.26115034 57.6226617C2.78057896 59.1728618 4.49636532 63.7256381 4.49636532 63.7256381C4.49636532 63.7256381 2.40680097 63.1281193 1.26836047 65.4344715C0.129919975 67.7408238 1.6087807 68.9385053 1.6087807 68.9385053C1.6087807 68.9385053 -0.334522693 71.0227709 0.0939962327 73.1925222L0.909978379 75.0309062C0.909978379 75.0309062 -1.31130635 79.8348519 1.18710439 82.0759883C3.68637046 84.3171246 5.49111085 83.0295508 5.49111085 83.0295508C5.49111085 83.0295508 3.1090246 85.4152197 4.91376499 87.4175247C6.71850538 89.420711 8.08446291 88.2529935 8.08446291 88.2529935C8.08446291 88.2529935 7.9835343 90.1292732 11.2491735 91.7543835Z"
        android:strokeColor="rgb8(0xff000000)"
        android:strokeWidth="1065353216.000000" />
</group>
</vector>
```

I tried to change it manually and whith [this](https://shapeshifter.design/) tool, but I did not succeed.

Here is my attempt to convert manually. It doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't display anything.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
height="28161"
width="28161"
viewBox="0 0 1121714176.000000 1121714176.000000">

<g transform="translate(1101529088.000000 1101529088.000000)">
    <path
        name="hair1"
        fill="rgb8(0xff0572cc)"
        d="M13.6680389 87.8907808C13.6680389 87.8907808 15.555746 93.5954113 17.6983406 93.7540446C19.8409352 93.9126779 21.0469466 91.9482686 21.0469466 91.9482686C21.0469466 91.9482686 23.4880504 94.1488653 25.7751953 93.9919946C28.0640509 93.8342426 28.8073302 90.4068815 28.8073302 90.4068815C28.8073302 90.4068815 29.1896615 91.8416318 31.0277596 91.7323511C32.8658578 91.6230703 33.4945233 89.4118981 33.4945233 89.4118981C33.4945233 89.4118981 33.2011461 87.8907808 36.7362134 87.8907808C40.2712807 87.8907808 38.842492 70.768022 39.5040522 70.3760024C40.8990908 69.5502278 38.8873613 67.9154344 38.2407339 66.6796779C37.5941065 65.4439213 36.364146 65.8530872 37.7933978 64.6968266C39.2226495 63.5405659 38.2407339 60.9275226 38.2407339 60.9275226C38.2407339 60.9275226 38.5614816 59.0935451 37.7839892 57.4472838C37.0064968 55.8010224 34.0812777 53.6374402 34.0812777 53.6374402C34.0812777 53.6374402 36.0605049 50.1140178 36.4505341 46.8223764C36.8414186 43.530735 38.408378 38.5205659 36.2846006 37.2938016C34.1608232 36.0670372 32.6451834 34.7838699 33.6561801 33.2865476C34.6680322 31.788344 35.5926409 29.6476755 35.1855052 28.8879981C34.7783694 28.1274395 36.4761939 24.939791 35.7406125 24.2091964C35.0058864 23.4794832 33.3901734 21.613779 34.2985309 20.3323743C35.2068883 19.0500883 38.6863594 18.2639721 39.5040522 17.142082C40.321745 16.0201919 40.7955962 14.7617008 40.7955962 14.7617008C40.7955962 14.7617008 42.8321303 15.8148498 44.2023645 15.1908921C45.573454 14.5660531 47.1489667 11.3123074 47.1489667 11.3123074C47.1489667 11.3123074 48.3370161 13.1330654 50.9705686 12.7964102C53.6049763 12.4597551 53.7734758 11.0338178 53.7734758 11.0338178C53.7734758 11.0338178 56.7902148 12.6386582 59.4143587 12.0781538C62.0376472 11.5176494 62.625257 9.24126125 62.625257 9.24126125C62.625257 9.24126125 65.3417762 11.1378107 67.2063894 8.78122462C69.0710027 6.42463849 69.780069 3.40355502 67.8726893 3.16384244L65.9653097 2.92412987L66.0730809 4.83742398C66.0730809 4.83742398 65.2331496 0.75790373 63.6148705 0.899792423C61.9965915 1.04168112 61.6903843 2.03930845 61.6903843 2.03930845L62.4516256 3.15855466C62.4516256 3.15855466 61.9102034 1.48585442 59.561475 1.59160996C57.2136018 1.69648422 57.3136751 3.01314078 57.3136751 3.01314078C57.3136751 3.01314078 56.9664122 0.522597636 53.7195902 0.559612078C50.4736235 0.595745224 50.1109647 3.65208055 50.1109647 3.65208055C50.1109647 3.65208055 50.3094007 -0.0925471327 46.6383363 0.00175156402C42.967272 0.0960502607 43.5771203 4.06981497 43.5771203 4.06981497C43.5771203 4.06981497 41.3729421 0.78610521 36.7362134 3.4308752C32.0994846 6.07652648 34.7056666 10.5244286 34.7056666 10.5244286C34.7056666 10.5244286 32.092642 8.86759165 29.7832586 11.0223609C27.4747305 13.1771302 27.1642467 16.7014338 27.1642467 16.7014338C27.1642467 16.7014338 25.8453322 15.9787709 24.1073073 17.8744391C22.3692824 19.7718699 23.5376594 22.6722158 23.5376594 22.6722158C23.5376594 22.6722158 21.4874401 23.5579185 21.2659103 25.4227413C21.0452359 27.2884455 21.3428898 28.4226737 21.3428898 28.4226737C21.3428898 28.4226737 18.2962143 29.5031429 17.8257844 32.5612408C17.3544991 35.62022 18.1183063 36.4706709 18.1183063 36.4706709C18.1183063 36.4706709 15.9902522 38.0094141 15.0493923 39.5613768C14.1093877 41.1133394 14.6337033 43.0671732 14.6337033 43.0671732C14.6337033 43.0671732 12.6484888 43.4082348 11.1183085 45.3726441C9.58812812 47.3361721 10.5537925 50.1298812 10.5537925 50.1298812C10.5537925 50.1298812 8.9175516 50.2585504 7.84668195 52.9068456C6.7758123 55.5560221 7.35657946 57.037481 7.35657946 57.037481C7.35657946 57.037481 5.74172172 56.0724617 4.26115034 57.6226617C2.78057896 59.1728618 4.49636532 63.7256381 4.49636532 63.7256381C4.49636532 63.7256381 2.40680097 63.1281193 1.26836047 65.4344715C0.129919975 67.7408238 1.6087807 68.9385053 1.6087807 68.9385053C1.6087807 68.9385053 -0.334522693 71.0227709 0.0939962327 73.1925222L0.909978379 75.0309062C0.909978379 75.0309062 -1.31130635 79.8348519 1.18710439 82.0759883C3.68637046 84.3171246 5.49111085 83.0295508 5.49111085 83.0295508C5.49111085 83.0295508 3.1090246 85.4152197 4.91376499 87.4175247C6.71850538 89.420711 8.08446291 88.2529935 8.08446291 88.2529935C8.08446291 88.2529935 7.9835343 90.1292732 11.2491735 91.7543835C13.7775207 93.0128745 13.6680389 87.8907808 13.6680389 87.8907808Z"
        fill-rule="1" />

    <path
        d="M11.2491735 91.7543835C13.7775207 93.0128745 13.6680389 87.8907808 13.6680389 87.8907808C13.6680389 87.8907808 15.555746 93.5954113 17.6983406 93.7540446C19.8409352 93.9126779 21.0469466 91.9482686 21.0469466 91.9482686C21.0469466 91.9482686 23.4880504 94.1488653 25.7751953 93.9919946C28.0640509 93.8342426 28.8073302 90.4068815 28.8073302 90.4068815C28.8073302 90.4068815 29.1896615 91.8416318 31.0277596 91.7323511C32.8658578 91.6230703 33.2772702 89.8851542 34.0812777 87.8907808C34.3521489 87.2188739 37.7731929 88.6849417 38.2407339 86.236289C38.6264912 84.2159624 39.682448 81.9103573 39.5040522 79.1689654C39.256883 75.3707399 38.4604451 71.3828691 38.9977154 71.0644997C40.3927541 70.2387251 40.1506795 68.4816333 39.5040522 67.6482127C38.8574248 66.814792 36.364146 65.8530872 37.7933978 64.6968266C39.2226495 63.5405659 38.2407339 60.9275226 38.2407339 60.9275226C38.2407339 60.9275226 38.5614816 59.0935451 37.7839892 57.4472838C37.0064968 55.8010224 34.0812777 53.6374402 34.0812777 53.6374402C34.0812777 53.6374402 36.0605049 50.1140178 36.4505341 46.8223764C36.8414186 43.530735 38.408378 38.5205659 36.2846006 37.2938016C34.1608232 36.0670372 32.6451834 34.7838699 33.6561801 33.2865476C34.6680322 31.788344 35.5926409 29.6476755 35.1855052 28.8879981C34.7783694 28.1274395 36.4761939 24.939791 35.7406125 24.2091964C35.0058864 23.4794832 33.3901734 21.613779 34.2985309 20.3323743C35.2068883 19.0500883 38.6863594 18.2639721 39.5040522 17.142082C40.321745 16.0201919 40.7955962 14.7617008 40.7955962 14.7617008C40.7955962 14.7617008 42.8321303 15.8148498 44.2023645 15.1908921C45.573454 14.5660531 47.1489667 11.3123074 47.1489667 11.3123074C47.1489667 11.3123074 48.3370161 13.1330654 50.9705686 12.7964102C53.6049763 12.4597551 53.7734758 11.0338178 53.7734758 11.0338178C53.7734758 11.0338178 56.7902148 12.6386582 59.4143587 12.0781538C62.0376472 11.5176494 62.625257 9.24126125 62.625257 9.24126125C62.625257 9.24126125 65.3417762 11.1378107 67.2063894 8.78122462C69.0710027 6.42463849 69.780069 3.40355502 67.8726893 3.16384244L65.9653097 2.92412987L66.0730809 4.83742398C66.0730809 4.83742398 65.2331496 0.75790373 63.6148705 0.899792423C61.9965915 1.04168112 61.6903843 2.03930845 61.6903843 2.03930845L62.4516256 3.15855466C62.4516256 3.15855466 61.9102034 1.48585442 59.561475 1.59160996C57.2136018 1.69648422 57.3136751 3.01314078 57.3136751 3.01314078C57.3136751 3.01314078 56.9664122 0.522597636 53.7195902 0.559612078C50.4736235 0.595745224 50.1109647 3.65208055 50.1109647 3.65208055C50.1109647 3.65208055 50.3094007 -0.0925471327 46.6383363 0.00175156402C42.967272 0.0960502607 43.5771203 4.06981497 43.5771203 4.06981497C43.5771203 4.06981497 41.3729421 0.78610521 36.7362134 3.4308752C32.0994846 6.07652648 34.7056666 10.5244286 34.7056666 10.5244286C34.7056666 10.5244286 32.092642 8.86759165 29.7832586 11.0223609C27.4747305 13.1771302 27.1642467 16.7014338 27.1642467 16.7014338C27.1642467 16.7014338 25.8453322 15.9787709 24.1073073 17.8744391C22.3692824 19.7718699 23.5376594 22.6722158 23.5376594 22.6722158C23.5376594 22.6722158 21.4874401 23.5579185 21.2659103 25.4227413C21.0452359 27.2884455 21.3428898 28.4226737 21.3428898 28.4226737C21.3428898 28.4226737 18.2962143 29.5031429 17.8257844 32.5612408C17.3544991 35.62022 18.1183063 36.4706709 18.1183063 36.4706709C18.1183063 36.4706709 15.9902522 38.0094141 15.0493923 39.5613768C14.1093877 41.1133394 14.6337033 43.0671732 14.6337033 43.0671732C14.6337033 43.0671732 12.6484888 43.4082348 11.1183085 45.3726441C9.58812812 47.3361721 10.5537925 50.1298812 10.5537925 50.1298812C10.5537925 50.1298812 8.9175516 50.2585504 7.84668195 52.9068456C6.7758123 55.5560221 7.35657946 57.037481 7.35657946 57.037481C7.35657946 57.037481 5.74172172 56.0724617 4.26115034 57.6226617C2.78057896 59.1728618 4.49636532 63.7256381 4.49636532 63.7256381C4.49636532 63.7256381 2.40680097 63.1281193 1.26836047 65.4344715C0.129919975 67.7408238 1.6087807 68.9385053 1.6087807 68.9385053C1.6087807 68.9385053 -0.334522693 71.0227709 0.0939962327 73.1925222L0.909978379 75.0309062C0.909978379 75.0309062 -1.31130635 79.8348519 1.18710439 82.0759883C3.68637046 84.3171246 5.49111085 83.0295508 5.49111085 83.0295508C5.49111085 83.0295508 3.1090246 85.4152197 4.91376499 87.4175247C6.71850538 89.420711 8.08446291 88.2529935 8.08446291 88.2529935C8.08446291 88.2529935 7.9835343 90.1292732 11.2491735 91.7543835Z"
        stroke="rgb8(0xff000000)"
        stroke-width="1065353216.000000" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the aforementioned [converter](https://shapeshifter.design/) works pretty fine.

But the **huge transform and viewBox values** are rather odd.
Removing them will result in a visible svg:

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')
console.log(svg.getBBox())
```

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 69 94" id="vector">
  <g id="group">
    <path fill="rgba(255, 5, 114, 0.8)" id="hair1" d="M 13.668 87.891 C 13.668 87.891 15.556 93.595 17.698 93.754 C 19.841 93.913 21.047 91.948 21.047 91.948 C 21.047 91.948 23.488 94.149 25.775 93.992 C 28.064 93.834 28.807 90.407 28.807 90.407 C 28.807 90.407 29.19 91.842 31.028 91.732 C 32.866 91.623 33.495 89.412 33.495 89.412 C 33.495 89.412 33.201 87.891 36.736 87.891 C 40.271 87.891 38.842 70.768 39.504 70.376 C 40.899 69.55 38.887 67.915 38.241 66.68 C 37.594 65.444 36.364 65.853 37.793 64.697 C 39.223 63.541 38.241 60.928 38.241 60.928 C 38.241 60.928 38.561 59.094 37.784 57.447 C 37.006 55.801 34.081 53.637 34.081 53.637 C 34.081 53.637 36.061 50.114 36.451 46.822 C 36.841 43.531 38.408 38.521 36.285 37.294 C 34.161 36.067 32.645 34.784 33.656 33.287 C 34.668 31.788 35.593 29.648 35.186 28.888 C 34.778 28.127 36.476 24.94 35.741 24.209 C 35.006 23.479 33.39 21.614 34.299 20.332 C 35.207 19.05 38.686 18.264 39.504 17.142 C 40.322 16.02 40.796 14.762 40.796 14.762 C 40.796 14.762 42.832 15.815 44.202 15.191 C 45.573 14.566 47.149 11.312 47.149 11.312 C 47.149 11.312 48.337 13.133 50.971 12.796 C 53.605 12.46 53.773 11.034 53.773 11.034 C 53.773 11.034 56.79 12.639 59.414 12.078 C 62.038 11.518 62.625 9.241 62.625 9.241 C 62.625 9.241 65.342 11.138 67.206 8.781 C 69.071 6.425 69.78 3.404 67.873 3.164 L 65.965 2.924 L 66.073 4.837 C 66.073 4.837 65.233 0.758 63.615 0.9 C 61.997 1.042 61.69 2.039 61.69 2.039 L 62.452 3.159 C 62.452 3.159 61.91 1.486 59.561 1.592 C 57.214 1.696 57.314 3.013 57.314 3.013 C 57.314 3.013 56.966 0.523 53.72 0.56 C 50.474 0.596 50.111 3.652 50.111 3.652 C 50.111 3.652 50.309 -0.093 46.638 0.002 C 42.967 0.096 43.577 4.07 43.577 4.07 C 43.577 4.07 41.373 0.786 36.736 3.431 C 32.099 6.077 34.706 10.524 34.706 10.524 C 34.706 10.524 32.093 8.868 29.783 11.022 C 27.475 13.177 27.164 16.701 27.164 16.701 C 27.164 16.701 25.845 15.979 24.107 17.874 C 22.369 19.772 23.538 22.672 23.538 22.672 C 23.538 22.672 21.487 23.558 21.266 25.423 C 21.045 27.288 21.343 28.423 21.343 28.423 C 21.343 28.423 18.296 29.503 17.826 32.561 C 17.354 35.62 18.118 36.471 18.118 36.471 C 18.118 36.471 15.99 38.009 15.049 39.561 C 14.109 41.113 14.634 43.067 14.634 43.067 C 14.634 43.067 12.648 43.408 11.118 45.373 C 9.588 47.336 10.554 50.13 10.554 50.13 C 10.554 50.13 8.918 50.259 7.847 52.907 C 6.776 55.556 7.357 57.037 7.357 57.037 C 7.357 57.037 5.742 56.072 4.261 57.623 C 2.781 59.173 4.496 63.726 4.496 63.726 C 4.496 63.726 2.407 63.128 1.268 65.434 C 0.13 67.741 1.609 68.939 1.609 68.939 C 1.609 68.939 -0.335 71.023 0.094 73.193 L 0.91 75.031 C 0.91 75.031 -1.311 79.835 1.187 82.076 C 3.686 84.317 5.491 83.03 5.491 83.03 C 5.491 83.03 3.109 85.415 4.914 87.418 C 6.719 89.421 8.084 88.253 8.084 88.253 C 8.084 88.253 7.984 90.129 11.249 91.754 C 13.778 93.013 13.668 87.891 13.668 87.891 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
    <path id="path" d="M 11.249 91.754 C 13.778 93.013 13.668 87.891 13.668 87.891 C 13.668 87.891 15.556 93.595 17.698 93.754 C 19.841 93.913 21.047 91.948 21.047 91.948 C 21.047 91.948 23.488 94.149 25.775 93.992 C 28.064 93.834 28.807 90.407 28.807 90.407 C 28.807 90.407 29.19 91.842 31.028 91.732 C 32.866 91.623 33.277 89.885 34.081 87.891 C 34.352 87.219 37.773 88.685 38.241 86.236 C 38.626 84.216 39.682 81.91 39.504 79.169 C 39.257 75.371 38.46 71.383 38.998 71.064 C 40.393 70.239 40.151 68.482 39.504 67.648 C 38.857 66.815 36.364 65.853 37.793 64.697 C 39.223 63.541 38.241 60.928 38.241 60.928 C 38.241 60.928 38.561 59.094 37.784 57.447 C 37.006 55.801 34.081 53.637 34.081 53.637 C 34.081 53.637 36.061 50.114 36.451 46.822 C 36.841 43.531 38.408 38.521 36.285 37.294 C 34.161 36.067 32.645 34.784 33.656 33.287 C 34.668 31.788 35.593 29.648 35.186 28.888 C 34.778 28.127 36.476 24.94 35.741 24.209 C 35.006 23.479 33.39 21.614 34.299 20.332 C 35.207 19.05 38.686 18.264 39.504 17.142 C 40.322 16.02 40.796 14.762 40.796 14.762 C 40.796 14.762 42.832 15.815 44.202 15.191 C 45.573 14.566 47.149 11.312 47.149 11.312 C 47.149 11.312 48.337 13.133 50.971 12.796 C 53.605 12.46 53.773 11.034 53.773 11.034 C 53.773 11.034 56.79 12.639 59.414 12.078 C 62.038 11.518 62.625 9.241 62.625 9.241 C 62.625 9.241 65.342 11.138 67.206 8.781 C 69.071 6.425 69.78 3.404 67.873 3.164 L 65.965 2.924 L 66.073 4.837 C 66.073 4.837 65.233 0.758 63.615 0.9 C 61.997 1.042 61.69 2.039 61.69 2.039 L 62.452 3.159 C 62.452 3.159 61.91 1.486 59.561 1.592 C 57.214 1.696 57.314 3.013 57.314 3.013 C 57.314 3.013 56.966 0.523 53.72 0.56 C 50.474 0.596 50.111 3.652 50.111 3.652 C 50.111 3.652 50.309 -0.093 46.638 0.002 C 42.967 0.096 43.577 4.07 43.577 4.07 C 43.577 4.07 41.373 0.786 36.736 3.431 C 32.099 6.077 34.706 10.524 34.706 10.524 C 34.706 10.524 32.093 8.868 29.783 11.022 C 27.475 13.177 27.164 16.701 27.164 16.701 C 27.164 16.701 25.845 15.979 24.107 17.874 C 22.369 19.772 23.538 22.672 23.538 22.672 C 23.538 22.672 21.487 23.558 21.266 25.423 C 21.045 27.288 21.343 28.423 21.343 28.423 C 21.343 28.423 18.296 29.503 17.826 32.561 C 17.354 35.62 18.118 36.471 18.118 36.471 C 18.118 36.471 15.99 38.009 15.049 39.561 C 14.109 41.113 14.634 43.067 14.634 43.067 C 14.634 43.067 12.648 43.408 11.118 45.373 C 9.588 47.336 10.554 50.13 10.554 50.13 C 10.554 50.13 8.918 50.259 7.847 52.907 C 6.776 55.556 7.357 57.037 7.357 57.037 C 7.357 57.037 5.742 56.072 4.261 57.623 C 2.781 59.173 4.496 63.726 4.496 63.726 C 4.496 63.726 2.407 63.128 1.268 65.434 C 0.13 67.741 1.609 68.939 1.609 68.939 C 1.609 68.939 -0.335 71.023 0.094 73.193 L 0.91 75.031 C 0.91 75.031 -1.311 79.835 1.187 82.076 C 3.686 84.317 5.491 83.03 5.491 83.03 C 5.491 83.03 3.109 85.415 4.914 87.418 C 6.719 89.421 8.084 88.253 8.084 88.253 C 8.084 88.253 7.984 90.129 11.249 91.754 Z" stroke-width="1" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can get the proper viewBox dimension via **getBBox()** in js.

Besides, the tool can't convert hex rgba color values.
But you can easily convert them to rgba by a [color converter](https://www.revilodesign.de/tools/hex-in-rgba-umwandeln-hex-to-rgba-converter/).